# Java-Eclipse : new Instance with Jaxb

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

When in my Eclipse project, I want create a new Instance with Jaxb, I have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hisrc/w3c/xlink/v_1_0/ShowType;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator$3.run(ReflectionNavigator.java:288)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator$3.run(ReflectionNavigator.java:285)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:64)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:417)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addToRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:309)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:264)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getBaseClass(ClassInfoImpl.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getBaseClass(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getBaseClass(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:278)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:275)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:417)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:387)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:454)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at Test_GetCapabilities_JaxB.main(Test_GetCapabilities_JaxB.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hisrc.w3c.xlink.v_1_0.ShowType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 75 more
```

My code is very easy :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;


import net.lampe.v_1_0.*; //Package containing all .java anotates


public class Test_GetCapabilities_JaxB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{

                    ObjectFactory objFactory = new ObjectFactory();
                    Home gc  = (Home)objFactory.createGetCapabilities();
                    // I have a class 'Home' in import net.lampe.v_1_0.*
                    JAXBContext jaxbContext;
                    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("net.lampe.v_1_0");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Why Have I this error ? I check jaxb library of my project and I have jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-core.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jaxb-jxc.jar, jaxb-xjc.jar.

Answer (score 0):

your org.hisrc.w3c.xlink.v_1_0.ShowType is not found that's why error occured check the jar file u imported .

Answer (score -1):

But I don't know what is the jar not founded...

In java Build Path, I have these jar checked :

Apache Tomcat

axb-api.jar

jaxb-core.jar

jaxb-impl.jar

jaxb-jxc.jar

jaxb-xjc.jar

JRE System Library JAVASE1.6

Maven Dependencies

Where is the org.hisrc.w3c.xlink.v_1_0.ShowType ?

Comment: Please use the comment function on other's answers or edit your question accordingly. Thanks...